# REQUEST UPDATE: NYC sound effect (still) needed

Tags: audio-recording

I've had not a single response to this question! Can anyone help??

--

Seeking someone to gather a particular sound effect for me. If you're in NYC and have access to the Chrysler building, pls PM me or leave a comment so I can reach you. Thanks!

Just an observation: When this forum was Social Sound Design I would have expected an answer within a couple of days. To date I have received no comments or even views. Lame.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anyone living in NYC that does sound.
I really miss Social Sound Design. I didn't see your comment until this morning since it's now over run with non-related sound design questions. Where did everyone go?

Comment: Lots of them left b/c of over moderation, but I and the other moderators are working to correct that.

Comment: That's really good to hear - I miss it.

Comment: @JayJennings I'm not in that part of the world so can't help with your request this time.  I also share your sadness at the demise of SSD at the community we now have.  However (in a shameless plug), I recently asked a question that I suspect you could contribute to with some examples?  I'd really value your input or comments if you have time.  Thanks  http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38117/examples-of-synthesized-sound-effects

Answer (score 1):

Your chances of finding a reader here who has access to the Chrysler Building are really slim. There are only a relatively small number of people who work there and there may not be a single sound designer or StackExchange user in that group.

You probably have a better chance of finding the sound you want in a stock library. It may or may not be specific to the Chrysler Building, but you might still find one that suits your needs.

As an example, here is a list of 180 various NYC street sounds you can buy the royalty-free rights to for $5 each:

[Pro Sound Effects — Track Search “nyc” 180 results](http://download.prosoundeffects.com/#!explorer?s=nyc)

There are also other stock sound vendors you can find with Google.

If you find the right sound, be sure to read the license before you buy and make sure the license is compatible with your project’s needs.